Use Tikzpicture instead of numbers in footnote
I want to have a tikzpicture as a footnote instead of a number. In my specific case I want a duck (from tikzducks) with a sign that has the number of the footnote. The working command for this is:
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\newcommand{\enteB}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \shuffleducks 
        \duck[signpost=\scalebox{0.9}{
            \parbox{0.5cm}{\color{white}
                \centering #1}}, scale=.4,\randomhead,
        \randomaccessories]\end{tikzpicture}}

I found for using Roman numerals this code on the Internet:
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\Roman{footnote}}

Wich works but when I do this with
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\enteB{\Arabic{footnote}}}

It won't compile when I simpy use:
\begin{document}
    \footnote{Test}
\end{document}

Are there any simple solutions for this?
edit:
The minimal example is:
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\enteB}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \shuffleducks 
        \duck[signpost=\scalebox{0.9}{
            \parbox{0.5cm}{\color{white}
                \centering #1}}, scale=.4,\randomhead,
        \randomaccessories]\end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\enteB{\arabic{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
    Tests
    \footnote{Test}
    \enteB{\arabic{footnote}}
\end{document}


make a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Well you can't redefine \thefootnote like this, the command should be expandable, (e.g. to allow to write it to the aux-file if you use a \label). So you must redefine the command that prints the marker:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\newcommand{\enteB}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \shuffleducks 
        \duck[signpost=\scalebox{0.9}{
            \parbox{0.5cm}{%
                \centering \textcolor{white}{#1}}}, scale=.4,\randomhead,
        \randomaccessories]\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\enteB{\@thefnmark}}}}  
\makeatother      

\begin{document}
some text with a footnote\footnote{Test\label{fn}}. Reference: footnote \ref{fn}
\end{document}



Be aware that the two ducks are different, if you want to keep them in sync you should set a seed.

(using the footnote number as seed might be a convenient way to keep them in sync)

Is there any list where I can find a list of options like @makefnmark for like chapters and so on, or like a documentation of all this detailed things?

@makefnmark is and internal command (as you can see from the @ in the name) and basically you have to study the code to find this things out. (With the new footnote code we are developing for the tagged PDF project they will be better interfaces, but that is not finished yet.).

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've read the documentation but I cannot find any documentation of the seed you mentioned, would you please give me an example?

@JoniBue1 I was thinking about something like this: https://pastebin.com/2tnBTEjx
